# Soap with CXF, set SSL and TLS protocol version

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

According the following code, how can I set protocols to TLSv1.2,TLSv1,SSLv3 ?

Using SoapUi, I'm able to request the service using the following config : -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1,SSLv3

Using CXF, i'm getting a "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)"

If i'm removing SSLv3, the output is "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Sorry for my poor knowledge about Soap and SSL...

```
URL wsdlLocation = this.getClass().getResource("service.wsdl");

Service service = new Service(wsdlLocation);
Soap stub = service.getSoap();

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) stub;

Map<String, Object> context = bp.getRequestContext();

context.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://url.to.service/service");

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(stub);

HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
try {
    TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("SSLv3");

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    String trustpass = "pass";

    File truststore = new File("/home/user/keystore.jks");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory
            .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustFactory.init(keyStore);
    TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
    tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);

    truststore = new File("/home/user/keystore.jks");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyFactory.init(keyStore, trustpass.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
    tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km);

    FiltersType filter = new FiltersType();
    filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT_.*");
    filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT1024_.*");
    filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_DES_.*");
    filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_NULL_.*");
    filter.getExclude().add(".*_DH_anon_.*");
    tlsParams.setCipherSuitesFilter(filter);

    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue and solved it through change the protocol name from 
`tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("SSL");` 
to 
`tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLSv1");`

Notice You should determine which protocol version(SSLv1? SSLv2? TLSv1....) previously before you change it.  Please refer to [determine the protocol name and version](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/how-to-determine-if-a-browser-is-using-an-ssl-or-tls-connection)

Plus if this workaround do not work for you please refer to [possible causes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205947/sslhandshakeexception-no-appropriate-protocol)
Hope this work for you and others