# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-boot

i am trying to use JPA in my application but when i add JPA and start the application i am getting this error. i have seen questions related to same error in stackoverflow and other sites suggested many answers but no luck to solve this error..i don't understand where i am doing wrong.

POM.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot.web</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-first-web-application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-first-web-application</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Entity class

```
   package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.model;

   import java.util.Date;

   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

   @Entity
   public class Todo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String user;

@Size(min=10, message="Enter at least 10 Characters...")
private String desc;

private Date targetDate;
private boolean isDone;

public Todo() {
        super();
}

public Todo(int id, String user, String desc, Date targetDate,
        boolean isDone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.user = user;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
    this.isDone = isDone;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public Date getTargetDate() {
    return targetDate;
}

public void setTargetDate(Date targetDate) {
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return isDone;
}

public void setDone(boolean isDone) {
    this.isDone = isDone;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Todo other = (Todo) obj;
    if (id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "Todo [id=%s, user=%s, desc=%s, targetDate=%s, isDone=%s]", id,
            user, desc, targetDate, isDone);
}

}
```

the Repository class

```
 package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.service;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

 import com.in28minutes.springboot.web.model.Todo;

 public interface TodoRepository  extends JpaRepository <Todo, Integer>{

 List<Todo> findByUser(String user);

 }
```

The controller class

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot.web.controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.in28minutes.springboot.web.model.Todo;
import com.in28minutes.springboot.web.service.TodoRepository;
import com.in28minutes.springboot.web.service.TodoService;

@Controller
public class TodoController {

@Autowired
TodoService service;

@Autowired
TodoRepository todorepository;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // Date - dd/MM/yyyy
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/list-todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTodos(ModelMap model) {
    String name = getLoggedInUserName(model);
    model.put("todos", service.retrieveTodos(name));
    return "list-todos";
}

private String getLoggedInUserName(ModelMap model) {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        return ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    }

    return principal.toString();
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/add-todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTodo(ModelMap model, @Valid Todo todo, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "todo";
    }

    todo.setUser(getLoggedInUserName(model));
    todorepository.save(todo);
    service.addTodo(getLoggedInUserName(model), todo.getDesc(), todo.getTargetDate(),
            false);
    return "redirect:/list-todos";
}
  }
```

error which i am getting is

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
       at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at com.in28minutes.springboot.web.SpringBootFirstWebApplication.main(SpringBootFirstWebApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.processDirectory(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(ExplodedArchiveDescriptor.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

i have tried

[Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou)

[Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' when add spring boot jpa dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503046/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-when-add-spring-boot-jpa-de?noredirect=1&lq=1)

no luck in these answers :(

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile`. So Javassist is not in the CLASSPATH. QED

Comment: Remove the hibernate dependencies from your list of dependencies. Those are already pulled in by the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you do not have `javassist` dependency in classpath or your IDE can not resolve classpath correctly.

1. Try add this to pom and re-import

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
       <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
       <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Try build the project using maven command