# Rest controller test with @WebMvcTest, Could not instantiate JAXBContext for PagedResources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, spring-boot-test, spring-mvc-test

I have some tests that were failing with `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'` this answer solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/47504698/6945345 but broke my Controller test with `Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources]: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.` This is because I think `@WebMvcTest` does not pick up the JAXB-API. What should I do to resolve this the best way?

The controller test class that is given the exception:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BiodiversityController.class)
@Import(SpecieResourceAssembler.class)
public class BiodiversityControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private SpecieService specieService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private SpecieResourceAssembler specieResourceAssembler;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new BiodiversityController(specieService, specieResourceAssembler))
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllSpecies_ShouldReturnSpecies() throws Exception {
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 20);
        given(specieService.getAllSpecies(pageRequest)).willReturn(new PageImpl<>(
            Collections.singletonList(createAnimaliaOrestias()), pageRequest, 1));

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/species?page=0&size=20"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content.[0].name").value(NAME_ORESTIAS));

        verify(specieService).getAllSpecies(pageRequest);
    }
}
```

My pom dependencies with the jaxb-api

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Java 9 or higher you need to add the following  VM options to start tests/application

```
--add-modules
java.xml.bind
```

Comment: Indeed is used java 10, I ended up doing this in my pom file