# How to configure a Spring boot project with Jetty and JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jetty

I'm developing an API in Spring Boot and I want to deploy it using Jetty (9.4.1.v20170120) that is already installed in my server, but I have had a lot of problems trying it, my question is, does anyone know what is the basic configuration to start a project with Spring Boot + Jetty + JPA + MySQL? If you have a template that I can use, I will appreciate it! Now, if you think that you can explain me and you want money just tell me! I'm very stressed to try to make it work and I've been wasting my time searching on Google but I have not found useful things :( Thanks in advance!

UPD: Among all the things that I tried, as Dirk says, I changed my pom.xml and it looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vibradeporte</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jetty-test</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then, if I try to execute it locally, it runs without problems but when I upload my war file to my server (I have installed jetty 9.4.1.v20170120), the server shows me this:

```html
    ** WARNING: JETTY_LOGS is Deprecated. Please configure logging within the jetty base.
    Starting Jetty: 2018-05-21 13:33:10.930:INFO::main: Logging initialized @144ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
    2018-05-21 13:33:11.141:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.  See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
    2018-05-21 13:33:11.196:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.1.v20170120
    2018-05-21 13:33:11.228:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///usr/share/jetty/jetty-distribution-9.4.1.v20170120/webapps/] at interval 1
    2018-05-21 13:33:13.446:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=1770ms
    2018-05-21 13:33:13.447:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5ae9a829{/jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war}
    MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-tree-6.1.1.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-6.1.1.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-analysis-6.1.1.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-commons-6.1.1.jar]
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:452)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:365)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:512)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1437)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:788)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    Suppressed: 
            |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-6.1.1.jar
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
            |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            |Caused by: 
            |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
            |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
 |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: 
        |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-analysis-6.1.1.jar
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Caused by: 
        |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: 
        |MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:878)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Suppressed: 
        |       |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |       |Caused by: 
        |       |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Suppressed: 
        |       |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |       |Caused by: 
        |       |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Caused by: 
        |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Caused by: 
        |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: 
        |java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-commons-6.1.1.jar
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        |Caused by: 
        |java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        |       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry module-info.class from jar file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war-_jetty-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-any-6309295758354144012.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-tree-6.1.1.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:891)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:959)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:940)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:887)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-05-21 13:33:14.139:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=230ms
FAILED Mon May 21 13:33:14 -05 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

exclude *tomcat* and add *jetty*

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I already did it and it works perfectly if I run locally, but when I try to deploy in my server it becomes ugly, because I got a RuntimeError but I don't understand why, I found an answer somewhere and says that is related to log4j, but I really don't understand how to fix it

Comment: you did not mention this... please update question en provide log-errors

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve it, two things to take into account:

1. Install the lastest version of jetty on your server, for this case 9.4.10.v20180503.
2. Add to your dependencies (I hava installed JDK 10), ([Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou)):

```html
<dependency>
  < groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That is all!