# Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext'

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, spring-boot-starter

I tried to build a spring starter project,I checked web,jdbc,jpa and thymeleaf but I get the this erreur:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at app.IntervApplication.main(IntervApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:450) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:54) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

This is the pom.xml

```
     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove from your dependencies:

```
hibernate-core
hibernate-entitymanager
```

Also, `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`

`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already contains this dependencies with right versions

Have a look at `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` [dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/pom.xml)

Comment: I removed the 3 dependencies but I get this error : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]

Comment: do you use Java 9? check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707331/8112217

Comment: thank you. I used https://start.spring.io/ to create the project and I import it, It's work without errors