# Spring Boot: + Spring Data Rest: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm a beginner at all of this and I don't understand why my project won't compile anymore as soon as I add spring-boot-starter-data-rest to my dependencies.
I'm use Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and H2.
Any help is highly appreciated.

**This is the error message:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:605) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.schnitzel.hunt.AppConfig.main(AppConfig.java:15) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$determineHibernatePropertiesCustomizers$0(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.lambda$getAdditionalProperties$0(HibernateProperties.java:109) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1378) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:109) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44b50107.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$4(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44b50107$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$11c968a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44b50107.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
```

**This is my dependency block**

```
dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.23.1-GA'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

**And this is the main method of my AppConfig**

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class AppConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }
```

**EDIT: Package Structure**

I'm not sure what's the best way to show you the package structure, so I did a screenshot.

[package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLqTc.png)

Comment: Please, show the package structure of your code.

Comment: Done! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou

Comment: which version of java do you use? looks like 11?

Comment: You have `AppConfig` and `Application` two root classes? What is the difference? Sometimes mistake could be because of trouble of package scanning

Comment: 1) It's java11!
2) You are right, this is confusing.
The Application.class is not in use. It contained a command line runner to fill the database but all the code and the annotations are commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions like ClassNotFoundException or NotSuchMethodException can occur when there are problems with library versions. Here you have several versions of spring. They are not all compatible with each other.

The easiest way is to use the Spring Initializr website to have the right dependencies.

In your case, you can downgrade your spring-boot-starter-data-rest version and use the same version as your spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Or do the opposite: increase version. For my part, I would use the same version number for all spring dependencies

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome thank you. I created a project with the Spring Initializr website and copied the dependencies from there. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the directory:

C:\Users\${user}.m2\repository\org\hibernate\

and installing the again by gradle clean build