# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I tried to implement [this User management template](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-security-forgot-password-send-email-reset-password/) and adapt it to my needs but the Springboot application does not start anymore, I run into this error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SynchronizationType`

I cannot figure what's wrong. Help please?

Here's my pom:

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.12</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
        <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's UserRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import sp.project.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findByEmail(String email);

    @Modifying
    @Query("update User u set u.password = :password where u.id = :id")
    void updatePassword(@Param("password") String password, @Param("id") Long id);

}
```

The User class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Long id;

@Column(name="username", nullable=false, unique =true)
private String username;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;
@Column(name="email", nullable=true)
private String email;
@Column(name="password", nullable=false)
private String password;

@Column(name="role", nullable=false)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

public User(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public User(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
    this.username = username;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + "*********" + '\'' +
            ", roles=" + roles +
            '}';
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import sp.project.model.User;
import sp.project.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findByEmail(String email);

    User save(UserRegistrationDto registration);

    void updatePassword(String password, Long userId);
}
```

and UserServiceImpl:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import sp.project.model.Role;
import sp.project.model.User;
import sp.project.repository.UserRepository;
import sp.project.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public User findByEmail(String email){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public User save(UserRegistrationDto registration){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(registration.getUsername());
        user.setFirstName(registration.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(registration.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(registration.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registration.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePassword(String password, Long userId) {
        userRepository.updatePassword(password, userId);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null){
             throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles){
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I got rid of the error for 'securityConfig' by removing the hibernate and validator dependencies but there is still another 'UnsatisfiedDependencyException' error prompting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'emailSender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at sp.project.ProjectApplication.main(ProjectApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-core` dependency as well as the `javax.validation` and `hibernate-validator` dependencies. Those are already included in the respective starters. Unrelated but troublesome you have 2 times a depenency on `commons-beanutils` remove the one with a version.

Comment: "The import org.apache.commons.beanutils cannot be resolved" removing all that.

Comment: If I keep the version in commons-beanutils the import is fine but I have yet another issue: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'emailSender'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: BeanUtils doesn’t, afaik, have anything related with java-mail. If you need mail add the `spring-boot-starter-mail` dependency.

Comment: @M. Deinum Unfortunately the same error remains even after adding the spring-boot-starter-mail dependency.

Comment: Do you have configuration for mail in your `application.properties`?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I pasted there the content of [Spring Boot + Hibernate + Email Configuration](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-security-forgot-password-send-email-reset-password/) from the template I followed.

Comment: The problem is you are following an old tutorial and upgraded versions yourself, without following the upgrade guides. The one you follow is for Spring Boot 1.5, however you are using 2.1 which changed mail properties to start with `spring.mail` instead of just `mail`. So basically you aren't following that tutorial ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you must remove this dependency from the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

`Spring Boot 2.1` already has `Hibernate` dependencies moreover it uses `Hibernare v.5` so here could be some problems with `Hibernate v.4` furthermore I didn't find such a dependency in the tutorial you are following

**UPD**
In case of exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] 
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error
>   activating Bean Validation integration

**[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707331/7214142)** (the newest version of *jaxb-api* is 2.3.1). As an option I also suggest you try to add a `@EnableTransactionManagement` to a configuration class

**UPD2**

I finally have managed to reproduce the exception (

> ...Error activating Bean Validation integration

) on my environment and figured out the root of the problem. Since you have already added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you should not add any other validation dependencies. So to get rid of the problem you have to remove this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well when I remove it I have another problem: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
// That's why I added the dependency

Comment: @lonelyknight I've extended the answer. Please add a full stack trace into the question

Comment: Thanks, I'd noticed! So compared to the pom I've provided, I have deleted Hibernate core and the duplicate commons-beanutils with no version. I have added jaxb-api.

Comment: I still have an error:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration

Comment: Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: I use Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). My Java version is build 1.8.0_191-b12

Comment: This gets rid of the BeanCreationException error indeed, but then as I answered M. Deinum who recommended a similar thing, I encounter an UnsatisfiedDependencyException as I wrote above in response to him.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause for your issue is **incorrect dependencies**. You can comment out the following dependencies from your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Next you can do a `mvn dependency:tree` on your project, and see that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE` pulls in transitively the correct versions of these two components:

1. `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final`
2. `javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final`

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` pulls in transitively:

1. `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final`

Repository operations on the database work fine with this setup.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
        <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.1.0.Final</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>5.4.1.Final</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>4.1.4.Final</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>
```

**dependency tree**

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
```

Comment: I wasn't able to do the mvn dependency:tree yet, I'm not used to using the terminal but the dependency hierarchy on Eclipse shows hibernate-validator and hibernate-core are correctly pulled by the dependencies you mentioned. javax.validation:validation-api does not seem to be pulled though. With the changes you mentioned it still doesn't work, I'm getting the error I listed in the latest update to my initial post.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the updated pom.xml. Please match with yours @lonelyknight

Comment: I have matched it with you except for the duplicate beanutils. So you deleted the tomcat version and commented out javax.validation, hibernate.validator and hibernate.core. I still have the same error I mentioned regarding 'emailService'