# Unsastistified dependencies: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Lately, I was starting to use MVC to do my project. So my own knowledge about it is still not that advanced. Recently, on one of my project, I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at apap.tutorial.gopud.GopudApplication.main(GopudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22e8720b.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$5(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22e8720b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ccd9c92f.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22e8720b.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

I have tried many solutions that I can find within StackOverflow and none of it works for me. I have tried these solutions:
[Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou)

### ***This is my Application properties***

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernet.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

### ***This is my POM XML***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>apap.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>gopud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gopud</name>
    <description>Project GOPUD Papa APAP 2019</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## ***Two of my Entities***

***Entity #1***

```
@Table(name = "restoran")
public class RestoranModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idRestoran;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "nama", nullable = false)
    private String nama;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "alamat", nullable = false)
    private String alamat;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nomorTelepon", nullable = false)
    private  Integer nomorTelepon;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    private Integer rating = 0;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restoran", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MenuModel> listMenu;
```

### ***Entity #2***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class MenuModel implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
   @Size(max = 20)
   @Column(name = "nama", nullable = false)
   private  String name;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "harga", nullable = false)
   private Integer harga;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "durasiMasak", nullable = false)
   private Integer durasiMasak;

   @NotNull
   @Size(max = 50)
   @Column(name = "deskripsi", nullable = false)
   private  String deskripsi;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "restoranId", referencedColumnName = "idRestoran", 
   nullable = false)
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   @JsonIgnore
   private RestoranModel restoran;
```

Right now I am stuck on how to solve the error, please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is wrong, try the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/gopud?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta
```