# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: spring, ssl, smtp, gmail, activiti

`org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MailActivityBehavior`: Ignoring email send error: Could not send e-mail in execution 622539
`org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException`: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
at `org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage`(Email.java:1421)
at `org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send`(Email.java:1448

Having issue is Sending SMS through GMAIL in spring ACTIVITI

```
Properties file:



 spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ZMIS_erp
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=admin.123
    spring.activiti.mail-server-use-ssl=false
    spring.activiti.mail-server-use-tls=true
    spring.activiti.mail-server-user-name="learnwithanandh@gmail.com"
    spring.activiti.mail-server-password="Anandh.30"
    email.base.url=http://localhost:9090
    zambart.upload.directory=c:/ZMIS/
    logging.level.root=info
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSLHandShakeException No Appropriate Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205947/sslhandshakeexception-no-appropriate-protocol)